# Android: Difference between VideoView and Intent.ACTION_VIEW

Tags: android-intent, android-permissions, android-sdcard, android-videoview

I have a correct VideoURI to play video in Activity.

```
Uri  videoUri = Uri.fromFile(file);
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.setDataAndType(videoUri, "video/*");
startActivity(intent);
```

This works and plays video on whole screen.

I am also trying to play this video using VideoView widget, but it fails to load the video.

```
mVideoView = (VideoView)findViewById(R.id.video_view);
mVideoView.setVideoURI(videoUri);
mVideoView.requestFocus();
mVideoView.start();
```

The video file is in sdcard/Movies/my_video.mp4;

When I run using VideoView the logcat gives..

```
W/VideoView: Unable to open content: file:///storage/emulated/0/Movies/my_video.mp4 
java.io.FileNotFoundException: /storage/emulated/0/Movies/my_video.mp4  (Permission denied)
```

Any helps would be great.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Solved.

There was no issue in the code.

1) I needed to manually give permission to the app to access the local storage.
(App setting)

2) Next I created an Intent to allow access to local storage in App settings.